# If $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$ through $f$ then $f[\overset{\,\,\,\circ}A]=\overset{\,\,\,\circ}B$ and $f[\partial A]=\partial B$ where $B:=f[A]$

Tags: general-topology

**Statement**

If $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$ through $f$ then $f[\overset{\,\,\circ}A\,]=\overset{\,\circ}B$ and $f[\partial A]=\partial B$ where $B:=f[A]$

A homeomorphism is an open map and so that $f[\overset{\,\,\circ}A\,]\subseteq\overset{\,\circ}B$. Clearly  $f^{-1}[\overset{\,\circ}B]$ is open and contained in $A$ so that $f^{-1}[\overset{\,\circ}B]\subseteq\overset{\,\,\circ}A$ and so $\overset{\,\circ}B=f\big[f^{-1}[\overset{\,\circ}B]\big]\subseteq f[\overset{\,\,\circ}A]$. Therefore we conclude that $f[\overset{\,\,\circ}A]=\overset{\,\circ}B$ for any $A\subseteq X$. Now a homeomorphism is a closed map so that if $B\subseteq f[\overline A]$ then $\overline B\subseteq f[\overline A]$. Then by continuity of $f$ it follows that $f[\overline A]\subseteq\overline B$. So we conclude that $f[\overline A]=\overline B$. Now if $f[\overset{\,\,\circ}A]=\overset{\,\circ}B$ then $\overset{\,\circ}B\cap f[\partial A]=f[\overset{\,\,\circ}A]\cap f[\partial A]=f[\overset{\,\,\circ}A\cap\partial A]=\emptyset$ so that if $\overset{\,\circ}B\cup f[\partial A]=f[\overset{\,\,\circ}A]\cup f[\partial A]=f[\overset{\,\,\circ}A\cup\partial A]=f[\overline A]=\overline B=\overset{\,\circ}B\cup\partial B$ then $f[\partial A]=f[\partial A]\setminus\overset{\,\circ}B=(\overset{\,\circ}B\cup f[\partial A])\setminus\overset{\,\circ}B=\overline B\setminus\overset{\,\circ}B=(\overset{\,\circ}B\cup\partial B)\setminus\overset{\,\circ}B=\partial B\setminus\overset{\,\circ}B=\partial B$.

So is the statement correct? and is the proof correct? So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct.

Open maps indeed obey $f[\operatorname{int}(A)] \subseteq \operatorname{int}(f[A])$, and the argument from continuity also checks out.

For closure you could use that $f$ is closed iff for all $A$, $\operatorname{cl}(f[A]) \subseteq f[\operatorname{cl}(A)]$ which is dual to $f$ is continuous iff for all $A$, $f[\operatorname{cl}(A)]\subseteq \operatorname{cl}(f[A])$ etc.

For the boundary we use that $f$ is a bijection so that $f[A\setminus B] = f[A]\setminus f[B]$ or $f[A \cap B]= f[A]\cap f[B]$, for all $A,B \subseteq X$ plus $f[X\setminus A]=Y\setminus f[A]$ etc. plus the usual
definitional expressions

$$\operatorname{Bd}(A) = \operatorname{cl}(A)\setminus \operatorname{int}(A)$$ or

$$\operatorname{Bd}(A) = \operatorname{cl}(A) \cap \operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)$$ combined with the preservation of interiors and/or closures we already know.

I don't see why you bother with $\operatorname{int}(B) \cap f[\operatorname{Bd}(A)]$ in your argument, as it's not needed:

Just write $$f[\operatorname{Bd}(A)]= f[\operatorname{cl}(A)\setminus \operatorname{int}(A)] = f[\operatorname{cl}(A)]\setminus f[\operatorname{int}(A)]=\\
\operatorname{cl}(f[A])\setminus \operatorname{int}(f[A]) = \operatorname{Bd}(f[A])$$

and be done with it.

Comment: I agree with you regarding your argument about $f[\text{Bd}(A)]$. Anyway thanks too much for your assistance!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro You're welcome, of course!